# Use MATLAB Compiler SDK generated package in KUKA Sunrise.Workbench

Tags: matlab, robotc

The MATLAB Compiler SDK allows to create a wrapper for a MATLAB function which can be accessed by Java software. Based on my understanding, KUKA's Sunrise.Workbench IDE uses most of the standard Java functions.

I was trying to read the package generated using the MATLAB Compiler SDK (the new version of MATLAB Builder JA) into the workbench platform. I could successfully read the package into Eclipse IDE, but not into Workbench.

The reason for using the Compiler SDK is that, I have some functions is MATLAB, and I want to use the same in the workbench programming.

Does anyone have experience with the same? Appreciate any help.